# Solr query returns different result though both queries looks to have same logic

Tags: solr

I am running following two queries and was expecting same results but that not the case , does anybody knows why?

**First Query**

```
_query_:"{!complexphrase inOrder=true}accounts:\"functional currency\"" AND (-_query_:"{!complexphrase inOrder=false}accounts:\"functional currency GBP\"~11" AND -_query_:"{!complexphrase inOrder=false}accounts:\"functional currency pound*\"~11" AND -_query_:"{!complexphrase inOrder=false}accounts:\"functional currency sterling\"~11" AND *:*)
```

**Second query**

```
_query_:"{!complexphrase inOrder=true}accounts:\"functional currency\"" AND (-accounts:"functional currency GBP"~11 AND -_query_:"{!complexphrase inOrder=false}accounts:\"functional currency pound*\"~11" AND -accounts:"functional currency sterling"~11 AND *:*)
```

The difference in two queries is

the first query is like:  P AND (Q AND B AND R AND *:*)

the second query is like: P AND (A AND B AND C AND *:*)

```
P : _query_:"{!complexphrase inOrder=true}accounts:\"functional currency\""

Q : -_query_:"{!complexphrase inOrder=false}accounts:\"functional currency GBP\"~11"

B : -_query_:"{!complexphrase inOrder=false}accounts:\"functional currency pound*\"~11"

R : -_query_:"{!complexphrase inOrder=false}accounts:\"functional currency sterling\"~11"

A : -accounts:"functional currency GBP"~11

C :  -accounts:"functional currency sterling"~11
```

I would like to believe that query Q is same as A 
while R is same as C.

Hence results pulled out by both queries should be same.

Comment: Could you please share diff between those lines?

Comment: These 2 lines are identical [Diff](https://www.diffchecker.com/iyHO7ckD)

Comment: Sorry for my typo earlier, I have updated the first query and elaborated the question further, if you have any more questions please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is Solr/Lucene is ignoring proximity search when grouped with a nested query as mentioned in below linked.

[Solr/Lucene is ignoring proximity search when grouped with a nested query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54575670/solr-lucene-is-ignoring-proximity-search-when-grouped-with-a-nested-query)

The issue was fixed once , proximity search was also turned into subquery.