# Solr/Lucene is ignoring proximity search when grouped with a nested query

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm encountering some confusing behaviour with solr queries (technically the Lucene parsing) which can be simplified down to a query like the following:

`_query_:"foo:\"a b\"~3" AND foo:"c d"~6`

Using the `debugQuery` option I can see this is parsed as:

`+PhraseQuery(foo:\"a b\"~3) +PhraseQuery(foo:\"c d\")`

or as parsedquery_toString, `+foo:\"a b\"~3 +foo:\"c d\"`

What has happened to the proximity of ~6 from the right hand side of the query? This only appears to happen when combining a nested query with a non-nested query as in the example above.

By comparison, by not using a nested query and writing

`foo:"a b"~3 AND foo:"c d"~6`

Gets correctly parsed as

`+PhraseQuery(foo:\"a b\"~3) +PhraseQuery(foo:\"c d\"~6)`

or as parsedquery_toString, `+foo:\"a b\"~3 +foo:\"c d\"~6`

Or alternatively using two nested queries as in:

`_query_:"foo:\"a b\"~3" AND _query_:"foo:\"c d\"~6"`

Also gets parsed correctly to be identical to the query without using nested queries.

Why is the proximity search of ~6 being dropped in the first example?

I am running Solr version 4.10.3 but have upgraded to 7.5.0 and I'm finding the same behaviour.

Comment: What is the version number at the top of your schema.xml?

Comment: The schema.xml version is 1.5

Comment: The solr and lucene version is 4.10.3

Comment: Which defType you’re using?

Comment: The default, so the Lucene parser, I'll try dismax now. Also tried upgrading to Solr 7.5.0 and finding the same behaviour